# Excel IF AND statement does not work

Tags: excel

I searched this online but I can't sims to find the answer: I have a column that consists of 1-10 values, if value is between 1-3 I want to show number 1 else if value is between 4-7 I want to show number 2 else if the value is between 8-10 i want to show number 3. how would I add multiple IF)AND??. I tried this but it shows true or false, it should be showing the numbers:

```
=IF(AND(L2="1",L2="2",L2="3"),1, IF(AND(L2="4",L2="5",L2="6"),2))
```

Comment: L2 cannot be both 1, 2 and 3, you sure you want to use `AND` and not `OR`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i tried IF(OR it still shows me true or false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it shows `FALSE` is that it ends up in the `ELSE` parameter of your innermost `IF` function. Since you haven't specified what to return in that case, it returns `FALSE`.

You have 2 problems with your functions:

1. You should use `OR` and not `AND` (I fail to see how the `L2` cell can contain 1, 2, and 3, at the same time)
2. You should use numbers and not strings (the *number* 1 is not equal to the *string* "1")

This expression should give you what you want:

```
=IF(AND(L2>=1;L2<=3);1;IF(AND(L2>=4;L2<=6);2;""))
```

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want, and returns blanks for all other values:

```
=IF(L2<=0,"",IF(L2<=3,1,IF(L2<=7,2,IF(L2<=10,3,""))))
```

Comment: it is still retuning false, it should return 1,2 and 3 number

Comment: It sounds like your number are formatted as text, as nentioned in Lasse's answer.